# wrap raw html using wrap()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var p = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>'

var x = $(p).wrap('<a></a>');

console.log(x);
```

I expect it will return `'<a><p>This is a paragraph.</p></a>'` but why it doesn't?Tried wrapInner() it doesn't work too.

Comment: What *does* it return??? Didn't you think that information would be useful to the person helping you?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.wrap()`, it will return the element on which is was called on, in this case the `p` element, but when you wrap a new `anchor` element is created and it is made as the parent of the `p`. So you can call `.parent()` to get the reference to the new `anchor` element.

The to print the new html, you can get the `outerHTML` of the new element.

```js
var p = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>'

var x = $(p).wrap('<a></a>').parent();

snippet.log(x[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Another choice is to create an `anchor` element, then assign the `p` as its content like

```js
var p = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>'

var x = $('<a></a>', {
  html: p
});

snippet.log(x[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to swap the selectors like,

```
var x = $('<a></a>').wrap(p);
```

```js
var p = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p>';
var x = $('<a></a>').wrap(p);
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Granted, this returns an `<a>`, but that would leave the DOM structure as: `<p>This is a paragraph.<a></a></p>`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot wrap normal strings even if it is html also.

if it is dom element then only you can use wrap and it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code will resolved your problems.

```
    $(function(){
      $('body').find('p').wrap("<a></a>");
    });
```